Laravel registration w/ referral code not linking in many-to-many table
I am fairly new with coding in general, but I am trying to create an app in Laravel 10 where a user can register and insert the referral code of another user, these users should be linked in a many-to-many table. The registration works but the link between users doesn't happen and the referral table remains empty.
I made the migrations first,
create_user_table
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('usertype')->default('agent');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('referral_code')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};

and create_referrals_table
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('referrals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_agent_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->foreignId('referred_client_id')->constrained('users');
            $table->string('referral_code_used');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('referrals');
    }
};

the model is where the random code is firstly generated upon subscription
User.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        // Generate a random referral code
        static::created(function ($user) {
            $user->referral_code = Str::random(10);
            $user->save();
        });
    }
}

and the Referral.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Referral extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_agent_id',
        'referred_client_id',
        'referral_code_used',
    ];
}

here things get complicated, at least for me, this is the controller, I try to validate the informations of the registration form, where the user can insert che referral code of another user, but the Rule::exists doesn't seem to work, the dds do not show up in the process and the if statement seems to never be contemplated.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Models\Referral;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     */
    public function create(): View
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {

        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'lowercase', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:' . User::class],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
            'referral_code_used' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:10', Rule::exists('users', 'referral_code')],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        dd($request);

        // If a referral code was provided, attempt to link it to the referrer
        if ($request->has('referral_code_used')) {
            $referrer = User::where('referral_code', $request->input('referral_code_used'))->first();

            dd($referrer);

            if ($referrer) {
                Referral::create([
                    'user_agent_id' => $referrer->id, // ID of the user who referred
                    'referred_client_id' => $user->id, // ID of the newly registered user
                    'referral_code_used' => $request->input('referral_code_used'), // The referral code used
                ]);
            }
        }

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}

It probably is something "easy", but I don't know where to look anymore, it has been weeks and I cannot find a solution, if some of you can help me out I will really appreciate it, thanks
